# Stochastic integral involving Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Suppose $W_t$ is the standard Wiener process. I am wondering whether I can use the independent increment property of the process as well as the fact that $W_t$ is zero-mean Gaussian to evaluate expectation of the following stochastic integral as I have:
$$ \mathbb{E}\Big[ \int\limits_{0}^t W^3_s dW_s \Big] =  \int\limits_{0}^t \mathbb{E}[W^3_s] \; \mathbb{E}[dW_s]  \\ = \int\limits_{0}^t \underbrace{\mathbb{E}[W^3_s]}_{=0} \; \mathbb{E}[dW_s] \\ = 0.$$
I am wondering whether I have used the techniques soundly.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(dW_s)$ doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @saz $\mathbb{E}[dW_s]$ is expectation of the infinitesimal increment in the Wiener process which is equal to zero. What would be wrong with that?

Comment: If it equals zero, then you are already done after the first "=". To make your argumentation sound, you will need to prove rigorously the first "=".

Comment: @saz can't it be done via just writing the integral as an infinite sum of product of increment and the cubed brownian motion? These turn out to be independent, so the expectation can be split

Comment: Well, yes, I didn't say that it is impossible. There are also general statements which say that $M_t := \int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$ is a martingale under certain assumptions on $f$, this implies in particular $\mathbb{E}(M_t)=\mathbb{E}(M_0)=0$.The best approach really depends on your background.

Comment: @saz the martingales idea was interesting. Had not thought about that. Thanks!